# Coinbase Pro API Authentication failed in Python

Tags: coinbase-api

I have used the following code to make a Coinbase API request, but I keep getting the 401 authentication error.

My request seems to be providing the right header information and I do have an active API in Coinbase Pro.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
import hashlib
import hmac
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from requests.auth import AuthBase

URL = 'https://api.exchange.coinbase.com'
request_path = '/accounts/accountid'

#coinbase pro
API_KEY = {API_KEY}
API_SECRET = {API_SECRET}
passphrase = {passphrase}



class Auth(AuthBase):
    VERSION = b'2021-03-30'

    def __init__(self, API_KEY, API_SECRET, passphrase):
        self.API_KEY = API_KEY
        self.API_SECRET = API_SECRET
        self.passphrase = passphrase

    def __call__(self, request):
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%s')
        message = f"{timestamp}{request.method}{request.path_url}{request.body or ''}"
        signature = hmac.new(self.API_SECRET.encode(),
                             message.encode('utf-8'),
                             digestmod=hashlib.sha256)
        signature_hex = signature.hexdigest()

        request.headers.update({
            'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature_hex,
            'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp.encode(),
            'CB-ACCESS-KEY': self.API_KEY.encode(),
            'CB-VERSION': self.VERSION,
            'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': self.passphrase,
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        })
        return request
        
auth = Auth(API_KEY, API_SECRET,passphrase)
response = requests.request("GET",f'{URL}{request_path}', auth=auth)    
response
```

Comment: did you get this solved? the json in the return should have told you what exactly was wrong. timestamp / signature / key / etc